# How to handle R eval with transmute?

Tags: r, eval

I'm pretty new to R. I am trying to aggregate some columns to a new column. Because only the aggregated columns must be saved to the DF, I use transmute.

Because the column names can differ I'm trying to concatenate some strings to make a piece of code and then work with parse and eval to work with this code.

The piece that I put together is:

```
transmute("aggr1" = as.numeric(val1) + as.numeric(val2), "aggr2" = as.numeric(val3) + as.numeric(val4))
```

If I make a new dataframe like this, it works perfectly:

```
data_aggr <- df %>%
  transmute("aggr1" = as.numeric(val1) + as.numeric(val2), "aggr2" = as.numeric(val3) + as.numeric(val4))
```

But if the string I put together looks like:

```
composed = "transmute(\"aggr1\" = as.numeric(val1) + as.numeric(val2), \"aggr2\" = as.numeric(val3) + as.numeric(val4))"
```

and then I use:

```
data_aggr <- df %>%
  eval(parse(text=composed))
```

it will not work. I get the error:

```
error in mutate(.data, !!!dots)
```

Is my solution possible. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? If you show the actual problem we may be able to show you a way that works. Concatenating strings to create pieces of code is definitely the wrong way to go about it!

Comment: Hi Konrad, I'm trying to make aggregation of columns. The user can choose 
(a) the new name of the aggregated column and (b) which columns should be in the aggregation. So if the user in the csv gives for example _aggr1, val1, val2_ then there should be a new column _aggr1_ which is an aggregation of _val1_ and _val2_. Because the user must be able to change the csv-file I thought this was the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule **you almost *never* want to use `parse` and `eval` in regular code** — in fact, their presence should be a warning that you‘re thinking about the problem wrongly. These are specialised tools for low-level R programming that should be completely absent in analysis code.

First off, in your code a likely cause of confusion is the use of double quotes around column names so you think they are strings. This is actually not the case! R silently accepts string literals in several places instead of variable names, and *treats them as variable names*.

So your initial code is actually equivalent to

```
transmute(aggr1 = as.numeric(val1) + as.numeric(val2), aggr2 = as.numeric(val3) + as.numeric(val4))
```

… *without quotes*, and this distinction is crucial for understanding what’s going on.

---

Now, how to generalise this so that you can *actually* use differing column names (i.e. computed values)? In a nutshell, you need to use use `!!` in front of the column name, and `:=` instead of `=`.

`!!` causes dplyr to interpret the column names as computed values, and using `:=` instead of `=` prevents R from seeing the values as function call argument names (it works around R limitations, since `!! x = y` would be syntactically invalid).

For example:

```
prefix = 'aggr'
data_aggr = df %>%
  transmute(
    !! paste0(prefix, 1) := as.numeric(val1) + as.numeric(val2),
    !! paste0(prefix, 2) := as.numeric(val3) + as.numeric(val4)
  )
```

How exactly the column names are computed obviously depends on your specific problem.

The details of how to dynamically call dplyr functions are explained in the vignette [*programming with dplyr*](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).